# Use CSS to create a three-sided effect with no content

Tags: css

I'm trying to create an effect on a `div` or `span` like that shown below with CSS (ignore the corner labels):

[image]

Where there is no content in the div/span. I thought I could do this by setting a width & height, then set the border width for left, top & right but leave the bottom. I've seen dropdown icons and many other things being created in a manner similar to this, but I can't get it to work - mine just comes out as a horizontal bar. What am I missing?

Comment: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ select the custom shape you can do it in a few seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your CSS it's not really possible to say what you "*missed*," as we can't see your code.

However there's a couple of ways to achieve this result; one using borders (as you attempted) and another using `clip-path`.

```css
/* Using CSS custom properties for easier theming if required: */
:root {
  --blockSize: 200px;
  --inlineSize: 50vw;
  --color: lime;
}

/* a simple reset to remove browser-default margin and padding,
   and setting the box-sizing algorithm to 'border-box' to
   include padding and borders in the elements' declared
   block-size and inline-size (these are logical properties
   used in place of 'height' and 'width' respectively, in
   the English language, which is left-to-right (inline axis)
   and top-to-bottom (block axis): */
*,::before,::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
/* setting the inline-size to the value of the --inlineSize
   custom property (equivalent to width, in the English
   language): */
  inline-size: var(--inlineSize);
  /* setting the margin on the block axis to 2em: */
  margin-block: 2em;
  /* setting margins to auto on the inline axis: */
  margin-inline: auto; 
}

.bordered {
  /* defining the border of the element(s) using border
     shorthand; here setting the border-size to
     --blockSize/2, using the calc() function, and the
     border-color to the value of the --color custom
     property: */
  border: calc(var(--blockSize) / 2) solid var(--color);
  /* setting the border of the elements' block-end edge
     (margin-bottom in English) to be transparent to
     "remove" that from the element to provide the
     "cut-out": */
  border-block-end-color: transparent;
}

.clipped {
  /* setting the block-size dimension ("height" in English): */
  block-size: var(--blockSize);
  background-color: var(--color);
  /* using clip-path to create the cut-out, with the polygon
     function: */
  clip-path: polygon(
    /* top-left point: */
    0 0,
    /* top-right point: */
    100% 0,
    /* bottom-right point: */
    100% 100%,
    /* setting this point to be 100% of the inline-size minus half
       of the --blockSize custom property (the width of the border
       in the previous element) and at height 50%: */
    calc(100% - (var(--blockSize) / 2)) 50%,
    /* setting this point to be half of the --blockSize custom property
       (the border-width of the previous element) and 50% of the height
       of the element: */
    calc(var(--blockSize) / 2) 50%,
    0 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered"></div>
<div class="clipped"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3p8hs0to/).

References:

- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`border-block-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-block-end).
- [`border-block-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-block-start).
- [`border-inline-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-inline-end).
- [`border-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-inline-start).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
- [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).
- [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [CSS Logical Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
- [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height).
- [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`polygon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/polygon).
- [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).
- [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).